# How to check a generic type in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, generics, typeid

In C++/CLI code I need to check if the type is a specific generic type. In C# it would be:

```
public static class type_helper {
    public static bool is_dict( Type t ) {
        return t.IsGenericType
            && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDictionary<,>);
    }
}
```

but in cpp++\cli it does not work the same way, compiler shows the syntax error:

```
class type_helper {
public:
    static bool is_dict( Type^ t ) {
        return t->IsGenericType && t->GetGenericTypeDefinition()
            == System::Collections::Generic::IDictionary<,>::typeid;
    }
};
```

The best way I find is compare strings like this:

```
class type_helper {
public:
    static bool is_dict( Type^ t ) {
        return t->IsGenericType
            && t->GetGenericTypeDefinition()->Name == "IDictionary`2";
    }
};
```

Does anybody know the better way?

PS:
Is it limitation of typeof (typeid) in c++\cli or I do not know "correct" systax?

Comment: "compiler shows the syntax error" -- what is the syntax error?

Comment: Sorry, I did not say it first time. It is:
    1>test.cpp(4): error C2059: syntax error : ','

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write:

```
return t->IsGenericType
    && t->GetGenericTypeDefinition() == System::Collections::Generic::IDictionary<int,int>::typeid->GetGenericTypeDefinition();
```