# Generic type definition in C++/CLI

Tags: generics, c++-cli

in C# it is possible to write

```
typeof(IInterface<>).
```

Is there something similar in C++/CLI?

```
ISYMessageDispatcher<>::typeid
```

doesn't compile because the compiler crashes.

[image]

Comment: Which version of the compiler?  If you run cl.exe from the command line, does it give any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I test it (using Visual Studio 2010 SP1), this doesn't crash the compiler, it's simply a syntax error.

```
#using <System.dll>

int main(void)
{
    System::Console::WriteLine( (System::Collections::Generic::List<>::typeid)->ToString() );
    return 0;
}
```

Attempting to compile gives:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 4.00.30319.269
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

generictypeid.cpp
generictypeid.cpp(5) : error C2976: 'System::Collections::Generic::List' : too few generic arguments
        c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll : see declaration of 'System::Collections::Generic::List'
```

For a workaround, see [my answer to a related question "How to check a generic type in C++/CLI?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6389266/103167)

Comment: So, the direct access to the generic type definition like in C# is not possible at all in C++/CLI?

Comment: @Antineutrino: I'm not aware of any.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
auto x = gcnew Generic::List<bool>;
if (x->GetType()->GetGenericTypeDefinition() == Generic::List::typeid)
{
   System::Console::WriteLine("The generic type is " + Generic::List::typeid); // or x->GetType::GetGenericTypeDefinition()
   System::Console::WriteLine("The specific type is " + Generic::List<bool>::typeid); // or x->GetType()
}
```

This yields output

> The generic type is System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]
>
> The specific type is System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Boolean]